# Fancybox 2.0 close button to the top corner of the window

Tags: jquery, position, fancybox

How do I move the close button of Fancybox 2.0 from the top corner of the dialog box to the top corner of the screen?  I asked on the FB Google Group and had no response, so thought to ask here, since a lot of FB questions are apparently being asked here, especially for FB 2.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change style for close button from:

```
#fancybox-close {
    position: absolute;
    top: -15px;
    right: -15px;
    ...
}
```

to something like:

```
#fancybox-close {
    position: fixed;
    top: 15px;
    right: 15px;
    ...
}
```

Though, in that case close button won't move even if you scroll the page.

Have a look, for example, at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) for more information about CSS positioning.

Comment: Thanks.  I wasn't sure if the outer divs would affect the positioning, but after looking at that example, it works fine.  Thanks!